# "dotnet restore" fails with "SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK"

Tags: .net, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-14.04, dotnet-cli

I've just followed the procedure here:
https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#ubuntu

and that's the output of `dotnet restore`

```
log  : Restoring packages for /home/test/project.json...
error: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
error:   An error occurred while sending the request.
error:   SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
```

I've added the relevant certificates to the trusted ones in order to make `curl` work but the error remains for `dotnet restore`.

I've tried to dig in the core source to find out how Nuget checks the SSL certificates without luck.
**Versions I've tried:**

- 1.0.0-preview1-002702
- 1.0.0-preview2-003100

I've configured curl using the `.curlrc` :

```
cacert=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

It has fixed `curl -I https://api.nuget.org` invocation.

However `dotnet restore -v Debug` still fails:

```
trace: Running restore with 8 concurrent jobs.
trace: Reading project file /home/user/test/project.json.
log  : Restoring packages for /home/user/test/project.json...
trace: Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0...
error: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
error:   An error occurred while sending the request.
error:   SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
trace: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.) ---> NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.CurlException: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
trace:    at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler.ThrowIfCURLEError(CURLcode error)
```

So dotnet core uses `libcurl` but it doesn't use the `.curlrc` obviously.

**EDIT: 21/06/2016**

Tried to update the certificates database with mozroots also but it failed to have any effect. (Seems to be more related to mono than to dotnetcore even if dotnet core building page mention it).

After digging into corefx code, Curl handler of System.Net.Http doesn't seem to set the right ssl options in all cases (like in [Simple Curl SSL sample](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simplessl.html)).

I've tried [Tyler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2879498/tylery86) solutions:

```
certmgr -ssl -m https://api.nuget.org
```

This isn't adding the last certificate even if I type `'y', 'yes', '1', 'true'` or whatever.

```
mozroots --url https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/raw-file/tip/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt --sync --import
```

This does something:

```
Importing certificates into user store...
194 new root certificates were added to your trust store.
Import process completed.
```

I'm not convinced that dotnet core used the libcurl nss build (just because their [development page](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/building/unix-instructions.md) tells about openssl version (and they're mutually exclusive). By the way, I've tried to use nss build of libcurl and dotnet restore still fails.

IMHO, the problem is not related to bad certificates registration but more on the fact that curl builtin certificate validation is not properly disabled (because the certificate validation is done in System.Net.Http and that is mandatory to offer to client code the ability to customize this validation).

Why is it happening on my machine and not elsewhere ?
It must be related to my version of libcurl.

However all of these are just assumptions for the moment.

**EDIT 22/05/2016:**

By looking at the code more thoroughly, especially when comparing master branch and the RC2 release, it's clear that SSL handling code is still changing a lot.

So I just grab the RC2 code and modify it to reflect what master branch does:

```
easy.SetCurlOption(Interop.Http.CURLoption.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```

However, it didn't change anything... But forecasted it was.
so here the code I used:

```
easy.SetCurlOption(Interop.Http.CURLoption.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

and then replace System.Net.Http.dll with the ssl certificates check disabled.
Not safe but unblocking me for the moment.

I didn't add that as an answer because it's more a hack than a fix.

(a real fix would be to disable completely certificates checks done by curl and always handle it in .Net core but in the current code on master, it's still not the case, it's more a kind of mix of both).

For the root cause, I think that I'm on a specific setup :

- libcurl built without any default certificate bundle path. `curlconfig --ca` return an empty string. And it doesn't read the `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` environment variable or `.curlrc` file.
- System.Net.Http (of dotnet-core) does neither setup a ca default nor disable the certificate validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Open SSL missing bundle certificates

The **root cause** is a missing configuration of **`openssl`**.
If you run the following command (or a similar one):

```
openssl verify /usr/share/ca-certificates/nuget.crt
```

and you receive the following result:

```
/usr/share/ca-certificates/nuget.crt: C = US, ST = Washington, L = Redmond, O = Microsoft Corporation, OU = Microsoft IT, CN = Microsoft IT SSL SHA2
error 2 at 1 depth lookup:unable to get issuer certificate
140075910137504:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
140075910137504:error:0B06F009:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_file:PEM lib:by_file.c:162:
```

It's because `openssl` (on which dotnet / libcurl ultimately relies to do the ssl checks) did not know where to find the ca bundle. I didn't seen any related parameter in `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` so even

```
export OPENSSL_CONF=/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

won't help on the openssl verification failure.

**However, the following has fixed both problems (openssl and nuget)**

```
export SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Now the output for `openssl`:

```
zsh/2 906 [1] # openssl verify /usr/share/ca-certificates/nuget.crt
/usr/share/ca-certificates/nuget.crt: OK
```

and for `dotnet restore`:

```
zsh 904 # dotnet restore
log  : Restoring packages for /home/user/test/project.json...
info :   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.netcore.dotnethostresolver/index.json
info :   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.netcore.dotnethostresolver/index.json 412ms
info :   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.netcore.dotnethost/index.json
info :   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.netcore.dotnethost/index.json 409ms
info : Committing restore...
log  : Lock file has not changed. Skipping lock file write. Path: /home/user/test/project.lock.json
log  : /home/user/test/project.json
log  : Restore completed in 4412ms.

NuGet Config files used:
    /home/user/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config

Feeds used:
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

Special thanks to [Tyler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2879498/tylery86) who help me to keep the motivation to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The [place where the certificates are imported from](http://mxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt?raw=1) currently redirects to [an under construction/outage page](https://hardhat.cdn.mozilla.net/en-US/outages.html). Once the maintenance is done, try again. I think this is a tad bit of a blunder on either Mozilla or the mozroots maintainer. All you see in the console output is either a stack trace or `Couldn't retrieve the file using the supplied information.` depending on your build of mozroots.

[image: Sadness]

The workaround is to somehow use certmgr to import the correct CA certs, and then import the endpoint certs (use `certmgr -ssl -m https://api.nuget.org`). If the CA for the certs are missing, the certs are considered invalid. If the certs are considered invalid, you can import them, but the restore will still panic, calling out the certs lack of matching issuer CA cert.

I say somehow, because I haven't figured out a good safe way to recommend doing it yet. I'm definitely going to have the proper mozroots certs baked into the next mono+dotnet docker image I build.

Newer builds of mozroots have command line parameters to substitute the certificate data endpoint. Going to use [a web.archive.org copy](http://web.archive.org/web/20141205154834/http://mxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt?raw=1) as a substitute for `mozroots --url ...` for now. Going to see if I can just use [this](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/raw-file/tip/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt) or maybe [this](https://hg.mozilla.org/services/services-central/raw-file/tip/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt) instead, or perhaps another `certdata.txt` from Mozilla's official mercurial repo.

Comment: I've tried your solution but as I mention in my question, I don't think in my case, neither the code nor its intend, is using the nss database of certificates used by mozroots

Comment: You ran mozroots first, followed by certmgr right? I'm using Mono 4.4.0.182 with a patch from ( https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/mono/mono/pull/2771.patch ) ; based on this docker image ( https://hub.docker.com/r/2020ip/dotnet-mono/~/dockerfile/ ) 
The patch is just for handling empty Tls streams, not cert verification though. You can check what version of libcurl is pulled in from that debian jessie build. When I revisit it in the future, I'll check the version.

Comment: In my build script, to accept when building the image, I have `( yes | certmgr -ssl -m https://api.nuget.org ) \ ` as part of the dockerfile. It adds a cert issued to *.vo.msecnd.net (and a crap load of alternate names including api.nuget.org) for me. However, I also have `( yes | certmgr -ssl -m https://www.nuget.org ) \ ` which adds nuget.org...

Comment: I'm not using mono... but dotnetcore ;)

Comment: I'm using both. See the "FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.0.0-preview1" line in the docker file? Using Mono for nuget.exe and other .NET executables that aren't ported to dotnet RC 2 / Preview 1.

Comment: Here's snippets of the builder's log (expiration 1 mo.) http://zerobin.org/?ad00b5e054c08b6b#7fKUE+IiAJxgsYVoGIZXju/C0rjaLmy+Jrw9wd69VKA= and http://zerobin.org/?93a8917f301dcdfc#+6Df8+oRsve5cFDkfi+/wdrYQr+UdeV5u6yumw62z7g=

Comment: Previously, I would get "SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK" from mono and dotnet, likely both stemming from https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/lib/strerror.c line 191 ; both using libcurl.

Comment: Sure. But I'm not buiding a docker image. I'm just invoking "dotnet restore". And by the way, I have mono installed with a nuget working like a charm... but as I've said the behavior of dotnet core/dotnet cli has changed a bit in the last version so maybe that's why it's working well for you an not for me (and I know that my build of libcurl doesn't include a default CAPATH). In the last version of the code (of System.Net.Http), they tried to disable the libcurl certificate validation so I don't think their intend is to continue to use it.

Comment: The docker image is a minimal debian jessie (a subset of ubuntu versions 14.04 to 15.10) with microsoft's official dotnet preview1 (the latest build, based on rc2) with mono 4.4.0 stacked on top by the 2020 guys. Your environment should not be sufficiently different. What is your environment precisely?

Comment: Can you post a link to where CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER is being disabled? I'm missing it... https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115358/discussion-between-fab-and-tylery86).

Answer (score 1):

If you are having this error in a docker container then run

- docker system prune --volumes.

Then stop the docker app in your machine.
Restart your machine and running everything from start.